# How to reset a program based on a user input

Tags: python-2.7

It's a guessing game and at the end of the code I want to ask if they would like to play the game again. If they do say yes then it start back from the top and if they say no the program ends. This is what i currently have not sure what i did wrong, ive had some help and this is what i have so far

```
import random

name = input('Entrez votre nom: ')


Kilo = input (name + ' Veux-tu jouer un jeu ')



def play(name):
    randomNumber = random.randrange(0,100)
    guessed = False

want_to_play = True

while want_to_play:


print("Un nombre aléatoire a été généré 1 a 100 ")



while guessed==False:
    userInput = int(input("Entrez votre estimation: "))
    if userInput==randomNumber:
        guessed = True
        print("Bien joué!")
    elif userInput>100:
        print("Notre fourchette est entre 0 et 100, essayez un peu plus bas")
    elif userInput<0:
        print("Notre fourchette est comprise entre 0 et 100, essayez un peu plus haut ")
    elif userInput>randomNumber:
        print("Essayez une fois de plus, un peu plus bas")
    elif userInput < randomNumber:
        print("Essayer une fois de plus, un peu plus haut")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate your game into a function. Then, use a loop around the function call:

```
name = input('Entrez votre nom: ')

def play(name):
    randomNumber = random.randrange(0,100)
    guesses = False
    # etc...


want_to_play = True

while want_to_play:

    play(name)  # This start your game

    want_to_play = input('Veux tu encore jouer? (O/N)')
    if want_to_play.lower() == 'o':
        want_to_play = True
    elif want_to_play.lower() == 'n':
        want_to_play = False # EDIT: oups, thanks Primusa
    else:
        print('invalid input!')
        want_to_play = False
```

Comment: im not the brightest with python i only just started my class but would i be inputting my code after the (play(name)  # This start your game)

Comment: like this `def play(name):
    randomNumber = ...` etc.